# CPanel, CRON, Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

Первый раз делаю CRON. Читал как и куда.

Есть скрипт `script.php`. Он выполняет запрос в CRM и получает токен, этот токен я вписываю в ACF поле и это поле тяну с нужных мне мест. Может тут проблема? В конце скрипта у меня `update_field('kommo', $access_token, 26);`

Он находится в теме.

Далее: `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);`

В CPanel, я создаю задачу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ничего не происходит. Я писал абсолютный путь типа `/home/folder/public_html/domain.com/wp-content/themes/site/script.php` и добавлял `/usr/local/bin/php` перед ним.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Скорее всего так как Вы запускаете конркетный скрипт и там есть WordPress (ACF) функция, вероятнее всего она не отрабатывает, так как сам по себе WordPress ведь не запускается. По идее Вам нужно подключить файл `wp-load.php` чтобы были доступены API WordPress и ACF.

Comment: @Simon можете уточнить пожалуйста, что такое фа?

Comment: Я тогда не дописал комментарий, обновите страницу.